# How do I call a C++ constructor via Rust FFI?

Tags: c++, rust, ffi

I am trying to use "xerces-c" via FFI in Rust without success. In C++, I would write the following code to use it:

```cpp
XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
{
  XercesDOMParser domParser;
  ParserErrorHandler parserErrorHandler;

  domParser.setErrorHandler(&parserErrorHandler);
  domParser.setDoSchema(true);
  domParser.setValidationSchemaFullChecking(true);

  domParser.parse(xmlFilePath.c_str());
  if(domParser.getErrorCount() != 0) {     
     // ...
  }
}
XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
```

How can I use these "complex" data types within Rust? I found many examples to export/create an FFI to use it in other languages but none to use complex types within Rust.

```
extern crate libc;

#[link(name = "xerces-c")]
extern {
    // How do i have to implement the constructor here? 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rust doesn't support FFI with C++.  If you want to use this library, you will have to find or write a translation layer that provides a pure C interface to the library, then bind to *that*.